# how to put variable from javascript to php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables

This is my codes using script, its a part of my codes, how can i put the `var x` into my `VALUES` in php, in the specified '`NULL`' value?

```
enter code here

var x = document.getElementById("name_stop");

<?php  require_once('dbconnect.php'); $result2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO log (status, code)VALUES('login','NULL')");  ?>
```

Comment: Looking at you;re planning to do with your database query, you also need to be very careful around SQL injection - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: Pls stop spreading hyperlinks to this horrible website ...

Answer (score 5):

You can't move JavaScript variables to PHP unless you refresh the page because while JavaScript is *client-side*, PHP is *server-side*.  When the page is loaded, PHP's job is done.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look on how to use ajax.

Moreover, for security of your apps, always check the data which are coming from client-side.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for AJAX. You will have to send a AJAX request to your phpscript.

The easiest way to send an AJAX request is using the [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) library.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "insert.php",
  data: { name: x }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```